# Cannot call method of type A with parameter type A?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

So I don't quite understand this. I'm trying to created a MethodCallExpression, but I'm getting a runtime error stating that the method cannot be called with exactly the type it expects? I'm fairly new to Expression trees, so I'm sure I've got something backwards, but just about every example I try to adapt leads to this.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var helper = new Helper();
            var expr = helper.GetMatchExpr<TestClass>(t => t.Name, "foo");
        }
    }

    public class Helper
    {
        public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetMatchExpr<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> member, string searchValue)
        {
            var memberExpr = member.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpr == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Expected member expression");

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, memberExpr.Member.Name);
            var propertyExpr = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(string));

            var matchMethod = typeof(Helper).GetMethod("IsMatch", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(string) });

            var valueExpr = Expression.Constant(searchValue, typeof(string));
            var matchExpr = Expression.Call(property, matchMethod, propertyExpr, valueExpr); // throws exception

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(matchExpr, parameter);
        }

        public bool IsMatch(object input, string searchValue)
        {
            if (input == null)
                return true;

            var qWords = GetWords(searchValue);
            var pWords = GetWords(input.ToString());

            return (
                from qWord in qWords
                from pWord in pWords
                where qWord.Equals(pWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                select qWord).Any();
        }

        public string[] GetWords(string input)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)
                ? new string[0]
                : input.Split(' ');
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The exception is

> Additional information: Method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.Object)'
> declared on type
> 'ConsoleApplication4.Helper`1[ConsoleApplication4.TestClass]' cannot
> be called with instance of type 'System.Object'

## To answer some questions:

As an exercise, I'm trying to build this class to where you can specify a collection of properties on object T that will be included in a search. So once all of those properties are set, you call Apply(...) and it will iterated through the collection of member expressions, grab their value, split it into individual words, do the same with the query phrase and then return any object that has any properties that match any of the words.

I've gone through probably 5 or 6 different examples that looked close to what I was trying to achieve and this is just kind of where I am at the moment.

So I guess I don't quite understand what "call IsMatch on the result of propertyExpr". Does that mean it's using the result like result.IsMatch or IsMatch(result)? If it's the latter, shouldn't anything be usable as object?

Comment: "I'm getting a runtime error stating that the method cannot be called with exactly the type it expects" - no, you're getting an exception saying that you can't call `Helper<T>.IsMatch` on an instance of `System.Object`. It doesn't help that you haven't provided a [mcve], so we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated. So evidently, I'm confused by the required parameters.

Comment: That's still not complete as it doesn't include PredicateBuilder, and it's unnecessarily verbose - why have a `Main` class which you just create an instance of and run within your `Program` class, for example? I strongly suspect you could get this down from an incomplete 122-line example to a complete sub-75-line example.

Comment: It also doesn't help that we don't know what you're trying to achieve. I can see what's wrong - you're trying to call `IsMatch` on the result of `propertyExpr`, which you've specified to be of type `object` (in the `Expression.Convert` call)... but I'm not going to wade through the rest of your code to try to reverse-engineer what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry Jon, I'm never sure how much is too much before others start saying that I'm asking them to do my homework. The whole thing has me a bit frazzled right now. Updated with some more info.

Comment: So I guess I don't quite understand what "call IsMatch on the result of propertyExpr". Does that mean it's using the result like `result.IsMatch` or `IsMatch(result)`? If it's the latter, shouldn't anything be usable as object?

Comment: Why all the downvotes still? You can literally copy paste the code and run it. I've clarified the actual area that's confusing me (the parameters of Expression.Call) and I don't know how to trim it down anymore without losing the context of the member selector.

Comment: Ok, I was able to trim it under 70 lines. There's no functional context, but it's still verifyable.

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't compile for me - you haven't declared `valueExpr` anywhere. If you could just update it to something that really compiles (including `using` directives) I suspect we'll be able to help you fix it...

Comment: Updated with the full file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your method call expression:

```
var matchExpr = Expression.Call(property, matchMethod, propertyExpr, valueExpr);
```

The first argument is the target of the method call - what you're trying to call `IsMatch` on. Now `IsMatch` is declared in your helper class, so you should call it on an instance of that class. For example:

```
var targetExpr = Expression.Constant(this, typeof(Helper));
var matchExpr = Expression.Call(targetExpr, matchMethod, propertyExpr, valueExpr);
```

That removes the exception - but it's still not clear that any of this code is going to help you. Having an expression tree representation of a query is typically useful when that expression tree can be converted into some other form, e.g. SQL... but no LINQ provider is going to know what your `Helper.IsMatch` method does.

If your aim was to do all the matching work in a database, this solution isn't going to help you. If your aim was just to do the matching work, you could do it a lot more simply using LINQ to Objects, and just calling methods appropriately and using delegates where required, without using `IQueryable<T>` at all.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Well at least I understand that a bit better. The part that I cut out uses this as a step to build a tree of binary expression. I had a working version of it (although I didn't test it on EF), but the underlying query felt like it would work (a chain of OR) and the source i got it from claimed it would :/

Comment: the end goal was abstraction that helps convert some filter strings that are read in from a GET request on a web page. I'm trying to simplify the process of filtering on "approved" fields. Originally did it on the finished collection (after the database call), but that poses a problem with paging. In the meanwhile, I was using as an opportunity to get familiar with Expression trees.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: Definitely good to be familiar with expression trees, but you'll need a bit more work for it to be done in the database, unfortunately :(